# F1 Score in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, precision, resnet

While training the model, I am trying to get the f1 score of binary classification problem on ResNeXt and ResNet. When I use tf.keras.metrics.F1Score function I get the following error while I am trying to fit the model:

**ValueError: FBetaScore expects 2D inputs with shape (batch_size, output_dim), with output_dim fully defined (not None). Received input shapes: y_pred.shape=(None, 2) and y_true.shape=(None, None).**

But, if I use tfa.metrics.F1Score function I get outputs without getting any error. Why might that happen? What is the difference between these two f1 score functions?

Also, while using tfa.metrics.F1Score I am also printing the precision, recall and accuracy values. They all have the same value how can that happen?

This is how I compile my models:

```
f1 =tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=2, average='weighted')
f1score = tf.keras.metrics.F1Score(average="weighted",threshold=0.5)

model.compile (
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer="adam" ,metrics=[ f1score, "Precision", "Recall"]
)
```

How I fit my model:

```
history = model.fit(
    training_set,
    validation_data = val_set,
    epochs = 5,
    steps_per_epoch = 95,
    validation_steps = 95

    )
```

Making trainig_Set and val_set:

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_Path,
    target_size = IMAGE_SIZE,
    batch_size = 32,
    class_mode = 'categorical' 
)
```